# D3 line do not read from the css file

Tags: css, d3.js

I have been staring at this for a long time now and can't see what's wrong...

I am drawing a line graph using d3 and want to keep the styling in a separate CSS file.

Line section:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("monotone")
  .x(function(d,i) { return xScale(graph_d.TimeStamp[i]) + 0.5; })
  .y(function(d) { return yScale(d) });

//Average line
  chart.select("#chartarea")
  .selectAll(".avgline")
  .data(graph_d.Data)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr("class", "avgline")
  .attr('d', function(d) { return line(graph_d.Data); });
```

CSS:

```
.avgline
{
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke: "grey";
}
```

This code does not render any line. Other parts of the CSS file are read and are working.

When putting the style into the line section it works:

```
//Average line
  chart.select("#chartarea")
  .selectAll(".avgline")
  .data(graph_d.Data)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr("class", "avgline")
  .attr('d', function(d) { return line(graph_d.Data); })
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('stroke-width', '1px')
  .attr('stroke', 'grey');
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colours in CSS are not written in quotes so you want

```
.avgline
{
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke: grey;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved it.